# kivy python popup on specific item in database

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm using Kivy to build a basic name and note taker (a dossier, per se) with Python. I am curious how to be able to click on a name and have that give more information (the notes on the person). I saw the CustomPopup() feature, but this seems more specific to a set item whereas I'd like to be able to click on any name and have the notes be visible. Just a point in the right direction would be awesome, thank you.

And here's some of the code, I'm very new to programming and so this is pretty much ripped from Derek Banas to suit my current needs.

Python Side:

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout  
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty  
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton  
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup  

class HumanListButton(ListItemButton):  
    pass  

class CustomPopup(Popup):  
    pass  


class HumanDB(BoxLayout):  
    first_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()  
    last_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()  
    notes_input = ObjectProperty()  
    human_list = ObjectProperty()  

    def submit_human(self):  
        # get the human name from textinput, synatx is to use varriable of the textinput.text  
        human_name = self.first_name_text_input.text + " " + self.last_name_text_input.text + " Notes: " + self.notes_input.text  
        # add to list view  
        self.human_list.adapter.data.extend([human_name])  
        # reset the listview, this makes sure it gets updated  
        self.human_list._trigger_reset_populate()  


    def delete_human(self):  
# this is where banas talks about building a database  
# if a list item is selected  
    if self.human_list.adapter.selection:  
    # get the text from the item selected  
        selection = self.human_list.adapter.selection[0].text  
    # remove the matching human  
        self.human_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)  
    # reset the listview  
        self.human_list._trigger_reset_populate()  


def replace_human(self):  

# if a list item is selected  
    if self.human_list.adapter.selection:  
    # get the human name from textinput  
        selection = self.human_list.adapter.selection[0].text  

    # remove matching item  
    self.human_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)  

    # get the huamn name from TextInputs  
        human_name = self.first_name_text_input.text + " " + self.last_name_text_input.text + " Notes: " + self.notes_input.text  
    # add the updated data to the list  
        self.human_list.adapter.data.extend([human_name])  
    # reset the listview  
        self.human_list._trigger_reset_populate()  

def open_popup(self):  
    the_popup = CustomPopup()  
    the_popup.open()  

class HumanDBApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return HumanDB()  


dbApp = HumanDBApp()  
dbApp.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

Use a RecycleView of names. When any name is clicked, populate the content of the Popup widget with notes of the person.

> Deprecated since version 1.10.0: [ListView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html) has been deprecated, use
> [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) instead.

## Example

[RecycleView, Popup, and SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052032/how-to-pass-more-then-one-parameter-in-pop-up-box-when-click-on-row)